# How to extract the same elements from two lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

here's my question:
How to extract the same elements from two equal length lists to another list?
For example: given two lists `[2,4,6,3,2,1,3,5]` and `[7,3,3,2,8,8,9,1]` the answer should be `[1,2,3,3]`. Note that the order is immaterial. I'm actually using the length of the return list.

I tried this:

```
sameElem as bs = length (nub (intersect as bs))
```

but the problem is `nub` removes all the duplications. The result of using my function to the former example is  `3` the length of `[1,3,2]` instead of `4` the length of `[1,3,3,2]`. Is there a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Is the position relevant here, like the example suggests? If so, you could just zip the list to [(1,1),(3,3),(3,3),(2,2),(4,5)...] and drop the entries where the fst isn't snd.

Comment: The position is not relevant here. I've changed the example. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, then there is another similar solution. Note that  `(\l-> \k-> [x|x<-l,y<-k,x==y]) [2,4,6,3,2,1,3,5] [7,3,3,2,8,8,9,1]` finds all matches, resturning `[2,3,3,2,1,3,3]`. You can eliminate the double counting by indexing the first list and in the end dropping values with repeated occurences.

Comment: NikolajK, or you can just use nub from Data.List on the result, to remove the duplicates.

Comment: @fgv: No, if he passes `[7,9,7]` and `[3,7,7,7]`, he wants the output to be `[7,7]`, see his example above. My method would first find six pairs and the deletion according to the indices would remove four of them, giving the right result. If we just apply `nub`, then we always end up with only one find.

Comment: This question does not seem to make sense? Why does `2` appear once while `3` appears twice? What logic is meant to apply?

Comment: Probably the title should be edited to reflect this particular case. As 'same elements' sounds just like `intersect` on it's own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the position seems to be irrelevant, you can simply sort the lists beforehand and then traverse both lists:

```
import Data.List (sort)

intersectSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersectSorted (x:xs) (y:ys) 
 | x == y    = x : intersectSorted xs ys
 | x < y     = intersectSorted xs (y:ys)
 | x > y     = intersectSorted (x:xs) ys
intersectSorted _ _ = []

intersect :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersect xs ys = intersectSorted (sort xs) (sort ys)
```

Note that it's also possible to achieve this with a `Map`:

```
import Data.Map.Strict (fromListWith, assocs, intersectionWith, Map)

type Counter a = Map a Int 

toCounter :: Ord a => [a] -> Counter a
toCounter = fromListWith (+) . flip zip (repeat 1)

intersectCounter :: Ord a => Counter a -> Counter a -> Counter a
intersectCounter = intersectionWith min

toList :: Counter a -> [a]
toList = concatMap (\(k,c) -> replicate c k) . assocs

intersect :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersect xs ys = toList $ intersectCounter (toCounter xs) (toCounter ys)
```

Comment: I'm sorry the example I gave is inappropriate. Actually the position should be immaterial.

Comment: @user3928256: Note that your current example is missing a `2` in the result.

Comment: This can also be done via `zip` as well: `intersectSorted :: Eq a, Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]; intersectSorted l k = filter (\(x,y) -> x == y) $ zip (sort l) (sort k)`.

Comment: @C.Quilley: Counter example: `[0,1,4,5] [1,2,3,4]`. The `zip` of the sorted lists doesn't have any pair with equal values, but the intersection should be `[1,4]`.

Comment: I don't much care for the partially-pointless `intersect`. It spoils the symmetry as it obfuscates.

Comment: @dfeuer Good point. I think I liked the pointless style a little bit too much in '14. I also replaced the `uncurry (flip replicate)`, since the lambda is easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a function for this. There is probably a more elegant version of this involving lambda's or folds, but this does work for your example:

```
import Data.List

same (x:xs) ys = if x `elem` ys
                 then x:same xs (delete x ys)
                 else same xs ys
same [] _ = []
same _ [] = []
```

The `delete x ys` in the then-clause is important, without that delete command items from the first list that occur at least once will be counted every time they're encountered.
Note that the output is not sorted, since you were only interested in the length of the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I would do in Java. I didn't know "delete" in Haskell before.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List (delete)

mutuals :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mutuals []       _                = []
mutuals (x : xs) ys | x `elem` ys = x : mutuals xs (delete x ys)
                    | otherwise   = mutuals xs ys
```

gives

```
mutuals [2,4,6,3,2,1,3,5] [7,3,3,2,8,8,9,1]  ==  [2,3,1,3]
```